# Div is not position correctly after fixed video in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

when i am placing div after video that div come up over video not
after video,also when i am making min-width: 100% to only width: 100%
then is show content coming before video when i am scaling browser

```css
body{
 font-family: 'Mina', sans-serif;
}


.navbar{
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.navbar-brand{
 padding: 0px;
}

.vid video{
 position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
   min-width: 100%; 
   min-height: 100%;
}

.content {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    top: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mina" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top container-fluid">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo1.png"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Countries</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">RECOMMENDED</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid vid">
  <video autoplay="" loop="" class="fillWidth" poster="" id="video-background">
     <source src="video/24.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <video autoplay="" loop="" class="fillWidth" poster="" id="video-background">
     <source src="video/24.webm" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

  <div class="content">
    <h1>Discover the Best Holiday Homes to stay</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row aft-vid">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two rows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"> video </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"> content </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `container-fluid vid`

Use seperate divs. See code below

```
<div class="container-fluid>
   <div class="vid>
    //video iframe
   </div>
</div>
```